# Kafka AdminClient API compatibility with Azure Event Hub

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

We are trying to migrate existing apache kafka clients to azure event hub. We modified the connection string for azure event hub without changing the code. But the existing code uses Kafka AdminClient api. I wanted to check if this would work. Right now, it's not working. Is AdminClient compatible with Azure event hub

We thought without changing the code it should seamlessly connect with azure event hub.

I think both Producer and Consumer APIs are compatible with AzureEventHub and there is no documentation on whether Admin API's are compatible. If anyone has come across this behaviour, please provide some insights